# Need some recommendations on organizing data

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm new here.  This question, to my mind, is allowed by the rules I saw in the "2 minute tour".  If I got it wrong, no need for nasty grams.  I'll delete if enough people say so.  But anyway, I have a bunch of data that I need to organize in a database.  This isn't the first I've ever constructed a database, but this might be the most complicated I've done and I want to "do it right".  So ....

I have a bunch of *simulation runs*.  To completely specify a simulation run, you need: code, code rev., date of run, begin time, time span, population model, time step, time step method, left boundary, and right boundary.

That specifies a run, but associated with each run is a set of data that comes out of analysis of the results: global max, final value, fitting coeff 1, fitting coeff2, and number of local maxima.

If *number of local maxima* is greater than zero, then I need to capture that info.  A *local maximum* will have a: value, location, and *simulation run*.

Well, I have figured out that I need to split off the *local maxima* into their own table, and link the *simulation run* of each maximum to the *simulation run* in the central table.

But what about that central table?  An aggregate key would have to have all of the information I listed above for specifying a particular run.  Is it a good thing to repeat all of that data in my *local maxima* table?  I thought about establishing a *simulation run* table that has all of the values needed to specify a run, and then an added unique numerical identifier for each run.  Then I could link to this identifier in my *local maxima* table.  This would cut down on the amount of data storage, but would it cause other problems?

Also, as I indicated, some of the data pertaining to a run *defines the run* while other data comes out of the analysis of the run.  Should I split these two types of data into two tables and link with that identifier I mentioned, or should I leave everything all together in one big table?

Thanks.

Comment: This is really a question of natural vs. surrogate key for primary key. You can see more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/590442/758494) and the links pointed to from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a surrogate key as a primary key for tables is a very common approach and it seems to fit your situation quite well. The foreign key in local maxima can then be a single column referencing the surrogate key.

If the relationship between the definition of the run and the outcome of the run is a one-to-one relationship, then you should at first consider having them in the same table, and only split them up if you feel it's more natural, convenient, or better for performance.